# Android-клиент не соединяется с сервером через сокет

Tags: java, android, сокет, клиент-сервер, android-asynctask

Мне нужно написать простенький клиент-сервер на Java. Клиент на андроид-телефоне, а сервер на ПК. Идея в том, что клиент посылает строку компьютеру по нажатию на кнопку, и компьютер, обработав строку, шлёт ответ. Клиент принимает результат и записывает его в TextView. Устанавливать соединение я решил через сокеты.

Но вот незадача: соединение не устанавливается и выдаётся ошибка. Когда я переделал клиент под ПК (из Android Studio в Eclipse), соедиение устанавливается. Всю голову сломал, никак не могу понять в чём дело. Помогите, пожалуйста.

**Вот консоль**:

```
08-28 08:33:36.197 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork (StrictMode.java:1273)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:592)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at client.server.myapplication.MyAsyncTask.onPreExecute (MainActivity.java:53)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at client.server.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick (MainActivity.java:32)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater $DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
08-28 08:33:36.209 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
08-28 08:33:36.210 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-28 08:33:36.210 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:726)
08-28 08:33:36.210 1179-1179/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-28 08:33:36.214 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.PrintWriter.println(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
08-28 08:33:36.214 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at client.server.myapplication.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground (MainActivity.java:66)
08-28 08:33:36.215 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at client.server.myapplication.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground (MainActivity.java:42)
08-28 08:33:36.215 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
08-28 08:33:36.215 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-28 08:33:36.215 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:234)
08-28 08:33:36.215 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-28 08:33:36.215 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-28 08:33:36.215 1179-19301/client.server.myapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Вот клиент:**

```
package client.server.myapplication;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText word;
    Button btn;
    TextView tv;
    MyAsyncTask connector;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        word=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.word);
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
        connector = new MyAsyncTask();
        connector.execute(word.getText().toString());
        String c = null;
        try {
            c = connector.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tv.setText(c);
    }
}
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    final String IP = "192.168.1.23";
    Socket s;
    Scanner in;
    PrintWriter out;
    final int port = 2017;
    public String answer;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
          try {
            s = new Socket(IP, port);
            out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        answer=params[0];
        try{
        out.println(answer);
        answer=in.nextLine();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String answer) {
        super.onPostExecute(answer);
    }
}
```

**Вот код сервера:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Server s = new Server();
    }

}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    Socket client;

    public ClientThread(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            processClient(client);
        } catch (Exception e1) {

        }

        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка при закрытии соединения");
        }
    }

    public void processClient(Socket s) throws Exception {

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());

        out.println("Соединение установлено");

        while (true) {
            String text = "";
            try {
                text = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println(text);
                if (text == null) {
                    return;
                }
                processCommand(text, out);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }

        }
    }

    public void processCommand(String command, PrintWriter out) throws Exception {

        switch (command) {
        case "a":
            out.println("Влево");
            break;
        case "d":
            out.println("Вправо");
            break;
        case "w":
            out.println("Вверх");
            break;
        case "s":
            out.println("Вниз");
            break;
        default:
            out.println("Неизвестная команда");
            break;
        }

    }

}

class Server {

    final int PORT = 2017;

    ServerSocket server = null;

    public Server() {

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Порт уже используется");
        }

        Socket client = null;

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Ожидаю соединение...");
                client = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка при подключении");
            }

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientThread(client));
            t.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Исключение `NetworkOnMainThreadException` говорит о том, что Вы пытаетесь выполнить сетевые операции на UI-треде, чего делать нельзя.

Метод `onPreExecute()` выполняется в UI-треде, а у Вас там работа с сетью в первой же строке:

```
s = new Socket(IP, port);
```

Решение – перенесите три строки из метода `onPreExecute()` в начало метода `doInBackground(...)`.

И еще, вызывая `get()` у асинстаска вы блокируете поток, в котором этот метод вызывается. Так как метод `get()` вызывается в UI-треде, то этим Вы блокируете весь интерфейс, а через 5 секунд блокировки получите ANR. Перенесите работу с результатом выполнения асинстаска в метод `onPostExecute(...)`.